# It is not appending correct file names?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem appending the imageNameArray where it is suppose to display file names which have been uploaded.

The problem is that lets say I previously uploaded 3 files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png), when I refresh page and upload another file (panda.png), then when I upload the file, it should display 'panda.png'. But instead it is just appending the names of the previously uploaded files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png) and it does not append panda.png.

If I refresh page again and upload another file (tiger.png), then when I upload the file, it should display 'tiger.png'. But instead it is just appending the names of the previously uploaded files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png and panda.png) and it does not append tiger.png.

If I upload another file (not refreshing page) such as monkey.png, then again it appends cat.png, dog.png and pig.png and panda.png. No monkey.png.

why is it messing up like this? All I want is that when a file is uploaded, it's name is appended but it doesn't want to do this :(

Below is the javascript code where the appending occurs:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){
    var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
    var result = '';
    if (success == 1) {
        result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';

        console.log(imageNameArray);
        for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++) {
            $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');
        }
        console.log((imageNameArray instanceof Array ? 'for' : 'for-in'));    
    } else {
        result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Below is the php script where it uploads a file and where the $_SESSION variable retrieve its file name:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $result = 0;
    $errors = array ();
    $dirImage = "ImageFiles/";

    if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

        $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

        if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
            if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                $result = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    $_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];

?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning session values to imageNameArray variable at the first line stopImageUpload function. So the imageNameArray variable contains the previously uploaded image names.  Try to change the line
`var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;`

as

```
var imageNameArray = new Array();
```